# Forbidden 403 when trying to update via Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Trying to update a calendar event, with Googles API. It's not working out for some reason... It's just telling me "forbidden", and I can't find anything on Googles error handling documentation that matches this error message.

A few important key points:

- The account running the auth has Super Admin rights
- Authorization has the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
- I have other "read only" API calls that work just fine.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

The data I'm trying to send:

```
let data = {
    'start': {
        dateTime: event_data.start.dateTime //This data is correct and is formatted to rfc3339
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': new Date().toISOString()
    } 
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
      if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
      }

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      } else {
        console.warn('request_error');
      }
    };

    xhr.open('PUT', 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'+calendar_id+'/events/'+event_id);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: Please include the code you are using to get the access token.  Im not seeing your authorization code here.

Comment: The authenticated user is a Super Admin right? And I understand that you're trying to update an event, is this event from the same authenticated admin or is trying to update an event from another user in the organization?

Comment: @LorenaGomez the event I was trying to update is an event that is not connected to the authorized user, however Super Admin rights should give access to all calendars and resources in a Google Workspace account. I've posted an answer below how this was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the problem relies with updating rights for Google Workspace accounts itself. **Allowing up to 48 hours for the changes to take effect** is what was necessary here, at the time of writing the post I had only waited around 12-14 hours.

Now that I've waited the up to 48 hours, **it works without having to change anything with the code**. I couldn't find where Google specifies how long these updates take, but it's consistent with other Google services as well that sometimes waiting up to 48 hours is actually necessary.

To summarize:

- The account running the authorization was given Super Admin rights in Google Workspace
- Waiting up to 48 hours for the changes to propogate
- The code above is correct and works as intended
- The event I was trying to update was not an event owned by the authorized account, thus giving Super Admin rights would give it the right to ALL calendars in the Google Workspace organization.

Answer (score 0):

Forbiden means that the user who is currently authenticated. This being the user who created the access token you are using.   Does not have permission to do what you are trying to do. So the user doesn't have access to write to calendar_id